# Is it possible to migrate from RHEL 6.9 to CENTOS 7?

Tags: centos, rhel

Is it possible to migrate from RHEL 6.9 to CENTOS 7? or do I need to upgrade my machine from RHEL 6.9 to RHEL 7 and then migrate to CENTOS 7 ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Upgrading first to RHEL 7 is not necessary.

Comment: thank's. I didn't find a guide, can you show me one, please? @ArtemS.Tashkinov

Comment: I'd love to get paid for that which is why it's the third time I leave such a question unanswered. It's not about greed, it's about "everyone should do what they do best".